# Best method to measure CPU time in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timing, cpu-time

I am curious what the current best method is for measuring CPU time in Python3. To be clear, the result I want is the total CPU clock time that the program has been running (i.e. not wall clock time).

I have used the `time` module for this in the past, but it is unclear to me if this is still the recommended method.

If the `time` module is the best option, I am wondering if `time.process_time()` or `time.clock()` is better.

Comment: maybe you can see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#list-of-hardware-clocks

Answer (score 2):

For cpu time `time.process_time()` or `time.thread_time()` is suitable - depending on what you are measuring and whether you are using multi-threading or not.

`time.clock()` is deprecated

Be mindful of I/O. If you are doing blocking I/O, it will get counted in CPU time. Non blocking I/O (like asyncio) would put the thread to sleep hence not get counted it in CPU time.

Documentation for this is pretty good and i would recommend you go through it in detail
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Comment: So `time.process_time()` is suitable for multi-threading measurements, whereas `time.thread_time()` is not suitable for multi-threading?

Comment: both the functions measure different things. if you want to measure current thread time, thread_time would probably be used. if you want to measure a process's time (which could have spawned multiple threads inside it), you will use process_time. depends on what you are trying to measure.